# How To Customize AspNetCore 3.x Identity Views?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am working on an AspNetCore 3.1 app using a scaffolded Identity. I managed to use External Identity Providers successfully, I could customize `Login.cshtml` and `Register.cshtml` using my own styling, what I want to do now is changing the pictured page below to fit my styling but I couldn't find where the view is, I am aware that aspnet core 3.x identity is not an mvc patterned anymore and that the code is inside all razor pages but I couldn't find any view or action that produce the shown elements. Please help and execuse my ignorance about razor pages if it is the reason :) . Thanks!

**View I want to Customize:**

[image]

**My Identity Files:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am aware that aspnet core 3.x identity is not an mvc patterned anymore and that the code is inside all razor pages but I couldn't find any view or action that produce the shown elements.

ASP.NET Core Identity is provided as a Razor Class Library in ASP.NET Core. And applications that include Identity can [apply the scaffolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) to selectively add the source code contained in the Identity Razor Class Library (RCL).

> what I want to do now is changing the pictured page below to fit my styling but I couldn't find where the view is.

To achieve your requirement, you can add and override `Account\ExternalLogin`, like below.

[image]

And the content of `ExternalLogin.cshtml` would be same as below, you can customize it with your expected style based on your actual requirement.

```
@page
@model ExternalLoginModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Register";
}

<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>
<h4>Associate your @Model.LoginProvider account.</h4>
<hr />

<p class="text-info">
    You've successfully authenticated with <strong>@Model.LoginProvider</strong>.
    Please enter an email address for this site below and click the Register button to finish
    logging in.
</p>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-page-handler="Confirmation" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I checked ExternalLogin.cshtml view and the content wasn't there nor the css classes I was looking for, it had a completely different content! But now I've just re-scaffolded identity and overrided the view and now I can see what I was looking for :)